# The output of linux command is not getting suppressed from console

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I am using the below command to remove write access for "other" users:

```
    df --local -P | awk {'if (NR!=1) print $6'} | xargs -I '{}' find '{}' -xdev -type f -perm -0002 | awk -F"/" {'if ($5!="tmp") print $0'} | xargs chmod o-w
```

I need all error and output messages to be suppressed from console. I'm however getting this messages still:

```
find: /data0101/track_logs/IMEI_TRACK_9_20141127_01010014.LOG: No such file or directory
find: /data0101/track_logs/IMEI_TRACK_4_20141123_01010014.LOG: No such file or directory
find: /data0101/track_logs/IMEI_TRACK_7_20141122_01010014.LOG: No such file or directory
```

I tried all combinations like this at the end of my command:

```
&> /dev/null
>/dev/null 2>&1
2&>1 >/dev/null
```

But it doesn't help. My shell is :

```
# echo $SHELL
/bin/bash
```

Kindly help

Comment: You are close, but the problem if because of find, so add the `&> /dev/null` where you are using your find command.

Comment: you can have a big curly brace over your command to make it an entity: `{ you_long_long_command ; } 2> /dev/null`. notice that the `;` after your command is necessary

Comment: GNU find has the -ignore_readdir_race option. That would avoid creating this specific error message in the first place. Which might be a good thing opposed to suppressing all error messages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are close to your answer. Since the error is coming from the find command, you need to redirect the error of `xargs -I '{}' find '{}' -xdev -type f -perm -0002` command.

So it would be:

```
xargs -I '{}' find '{}' -xdev -type f -perm -0002 2>/dev/null
```

---

Also, as stated by @HuStmpHrrr to redirect the error messages for your entire long command, use `{long_command;} 2>/dev/null`